# Atom Messes Up Formatting In Emacs File

Tags: linux, emacs, scp, text-formatting, atom-editor

I used the `scp` command to copy a file from a remote Linux computer to my local Linux computer (this file was edited using Emacs on that remote computer). I tried to open the file in Atom on my local computer, and the formatting and new lines did not preserve. I'm not sure how to come up with a fix for this.

[Sample of code when opened in Emacs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4Xu5.png)
[Sample of code when opened in Atom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFXaw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not atom "messing up" the formatting, but that atom does not recognize mac line endings.  The emacs image hints that you have mac line endings (notice the *-UU-(MAC)* thing on the status line.  Atom seems to ignore the mac line endings (0d), probably expecting the unix ones.  I don't know atom well enough but you can convert it to unix (0a) line ending on emacs with

```
C-x
RET
f
utf-8-unix
```

You may choose another encoding besides utf-8 if you wish.

I am sure there are also atom-specific approach, just search for "atom mac line endings"

Comment: This is perfect, the code provided for emacs works, I'm yet to find an atom-specific fix, but thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Atom may not recognise the line endings. UNIX uses an LF character, macOS uses a single LF character, and older mac operating systems may use a single CR character for new lines. You can switch between them at the bottom right corner of the atom text editor next to the encoding and syntax selection.